# Importing data from Excel into MSSQL Server - why does the dubled sheet has "sheet$_"?

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

Each time when I'm trying to import from Excel into a MSSQL database, the sheets are doubled and one of them has "_". Could anyone explain what's the difference? I looked out for any answers but couldn't find one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recognizing your remark, after doing some tests, it seems that the extra row in the import wizard is created if a named range is defined in the excel sheet.

In this way it should be possible to import only a named range from a sheet with other entries.